# How to remove a lines that contain duplicate text at specific part of a column?

Tags: notepad++

Suppose we have lines like these which also contains other matter

```
0000000470{201906037143845092  xyz....
0000000470{201906037143845092  abc,,,,
0000000470{201906037143845092  pqr////
```

Let's say I just want to remove the entire lines containing 201906037143845092
Can you please help me do it?

I expect the result to have the other lines except the lines containing 201906037143845092

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*201906037143845092.*(?:\R|$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                       # beginning of line
  .*                    # 0 or more any character butt newline
  201906037143845092    # the string to search
  .*                    # 0 or more any character butt newline
  (?:\R|$)              # any kind of linebreak OR end of line
```

**Given:**

```
0000000470{201906037143845092  xyz....
0000000470{201906037143845092  abc,,,,
0000000470{201906037143845092  pqr////
0000000470{201806037143845092  xyz....
0000000470{201706037143845092  abc,,,,
0000000470{201606037143845092  pqr////
```

**Result for given example:**

```
0000000470{201806037143845092  xyz....
0000000470{201706037143845092  abc,,,,
0000000470{201606037143845092  pqr////
```

**Screen capture:**

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]